# How to do Windows Handle Inheritance

Tags: c, windows, inheritance, handle

I have parent and child processes, in the parent process i'm stating that handles are to be inherited as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx:

```
...
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
// Create a pipe for the Parent process's STDOUT.  
if ( ! CreatePipe(&hChildReadPipe, &hParentWritePipe, &sa, 0) )
{
    _tprintf(_T("Error creating Pipe\n")); 
}
...

// Start the child process. 
if( !CreateProcess(
        _T("..\\Debug\\Child.exe"),
        _T("hChildReadPipe"),   // Command line.
        NULL,                   // Process handle not inheritable.
        NULL,                   // Thread handle not inheritable.
        TRUE,                   // Set handle inheritance to TRUE.
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,     // No creation flags.
        NULL,                   // Use parent's environment block.
        NULL,                   // Use parent's starting directory.
        &si,                    // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.
        &pi )                   // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.
    )
    {
        printf( "\nCreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
    return FALSE;
    }
```

My question is how do i get the hChildReadPipe handle passed by command line to the child process, in MSDN they recommend uging GetCommandLine() but this only returns the command line string, how do i convert this string to a usable HANDLE?

I tried CreateFile() but it doesn't work...

Thanks

Comment: I suggest reading [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to redirect I/O, i want to get the inherited handle

Comment: Then just cast the handle to an integer value (`UINT_PTR value = (UINT_PTR)hChildReadPipe;`) and pass that to the command line as a string (`__ultoa()`). Then the child will need to read the integer value off of the command line (`UINT_PTR value = strtoul()`) and cast that to a HANDLE (`HANDLE hChildReadPipe = (HANDLE)value;`). Note that this is generally not the ideal way to do this.

Comment: Ok thanks i will try it. I know it's not the ideal way but its a requirement...

Comment: Read also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx the key here is `"An inherited handle ... has the same value ..."`

Comment: Ok it totally worked :) thanks. How can i accept your answer?

Comment: It looks like someone converted it to a comment. I'll repost it with the correct info and you can then just hit the checkmark :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first suggestion is to read [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx).

However if your requirements are to not touch stdin or stdout (or other related HANDLEs) then you can just cast the handle to an integer value (`UINT_PTR value = (UINT_PTR)hChildReadPipe;`) and pass that to the command line as a string (`__ultoa()`). Then the child will need to read the integer value off of the command line (`UINT_PTR value = strtoul()`) and cast that back to a HANDLE (`HANDLE hChildReadPipe = (HANDLE)value;`).

The important thing to remember is an [excerpt on handle inheritance from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `"An inherited handle ... has the same value ..."`.